# Kafka Producer/consumer API or kafka streams for simple processing use case?

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api

My use case is to create a java service that consumes X records from debezium topics, parses the record keys, for the set of keys (deduplicated) calls an API exposed by another service to fetch related data and puts a record for each unique key on another kafka topic (in the same kafka cluster) with at least once semantics.

Wonder if I should stick with using simple Kafka producer/consumer APIs for this or does Kafka streams offer something for this use case that would be difficult to implement/maintain with kafka producer/consumer APIs?

Note: For kafka streams, I have been able to implement processing X records at a time, using low level kafka-streams processor APIs (punctuate with a state store).

Comment: can you explain more on your definition of "batching"? I find it difficult to understand "implement batching using low level kafka-**streams** processor API. Also, what do you mean with "for a single batch go to another service". What batch, and what other service?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Batch here simply means X kafka records operated on at a time. For the X records, I will call an API in another service to fetch X hydrated objects. Updated my question accordingly. Please let me know if this answers your question.